# Safari image width change

Tags: css, safari, sass

I currently put my website online, but I have a problem with the image size in safari,
In my css I put the width like that :

```
img {
    width: 450%;
}
```

here is the site :

http://antoninmarchard.com/

I don't understand why the image display well in chrome, mozilla but doesn't in Safari ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code are not good, Also it now looking good in IE. I have clean up html and css code you may apply these changes to fix your issue:

**HTML Changes**  lets make html simple for that particular section:

```
<div class="inner-banner">
        <div class="left">                  
                <h1> Donnez vie à vos idées, créons ensemble. </h1>
                <button class="btn btn-custom-am" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact_modal"> Contactez-moi </button>
        </div>              
        <div class="right">                 
                <img src="src/img/banner-design.svg" alt="cube with smoke, smartphone and computer">
        </div>              
</div>
```

**CSS Changes** need to fix code

```
.banner .inner-banner{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.banner .inner-banner .left{
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 4%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    color: #ffffff;
}

.banner .inner-banner .right{
    width: 70%;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Remove `width:450%` from image, we don't need it